# Yii2: How to use a PostgreSQL's function?

Tags: postgresql, model-view-controller, yii2

I have a table called `persons` that have three columns called `id`, `name` and `birth`.

I can get `name` and `birth` but I need to calculate the **age of the person** using its `birth` date. I want to use the PostgreSQL's function: [`age(timestamp)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html). But I don't know to use it.

Is there any way to use a PostgreSQL's function?

I was trying to use it in the view but then I realize it will not work:

```
$person = \app\models\Persons::findOne(['id' => 1234]);
$myName  = $person->name;
$myBirth = $person->birth;
$myAge   = $person->age(birth);
```

Should I change the model? I don't know where to use the `age` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your model you should define public property `public $age;`. Then, your select statement should be like this:

```
$person = Persons::find()->select(['name', 'birth', 'age(birth) as age'])->andWhere(['id' => 1234])->one();
```

Then you can access it as property:

```
$person->age;
```